# Extending a finite group to avoid the center

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Does there exist a finite group $\Gamma$ and a surjection $f\colon \Gamma \rightarrow G$ such that the center $Z(\Gamma)$ lies in the kernel of $f$?

Of course, this is only an interesting question if $Z(G) \neq 1$.  It is also pretty trivial if we don't insist that $\Gamma$ is finite since we can then just take $\Gamma$ to be a free group.

I don't have a strong feeling as to whether or not such a $\Gamma$ exists.

Comment: Let $\Gamma = G\wr G$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes: Thanks for this too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every finite group $G$ is quotient of a finite group with trivial center. Namely choose $p$ odd prime not dividing the order of $G$. Let $V_p$ be the abelian group of functions $G\to\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ with sum zero. The action of $G$ on $V_p$ by translation $g\cdot f(h)=f(g^{-1}h)$ is faithful and fixes no nonzero element. So the semidirect product $G\ltimes V_p$ has trivial center and admits $G$ as quotient.

Comment: That's a really nice construction, thanks!